# Nest instance throw incomprehensive import errors on start in production

Tags: node.js, nestjs, debian, production

I have a nestjs app that i build using `NODE_ENV=production nest build`.
It starts on my macbook using the `NODE_ENV=production nest start` command, it also starts with the same command using the local vagrant box instance of our prod machine.
But it throws this on the prod machine running the same node version 16.20:

```
[Nest] 1108076  - 06/12/2023, 9:54:51 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 1108076  - 06/12/2023, 9:54:51 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot create the AppModule instance.
Received an unexpected value at index [3] of the AppModule "imports" array.

Scope []
Error: Nest cannot create the AppModule instance.
Received an unexpected value at index [3] of the AppModule "imports" array.

Scope []
    at DependenciesScanner.scanForModules (/home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:56:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async DependenciesScanner.scan (/home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:27:9)
    at async /home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:107:17
    at async Function.asyncRun (/home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:22:13)
    at async NestFactoryStatic.initialize (/home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:106:13)
    at async NestFactoryStatic.create (/home/check-inventory/test/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:42:9)
    at async bootstrap (/home/check-inventory/test/dist/src/main.js:13:17)
```

I even transferred my locally built dist and node_modules via scp and adjusted all the ownerships, with no luck still...

My app.module file:

```js
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { UsersModule } from "./users/users.module";
import { GroupsModule } from "./groups/groups.module";
import { RequestsModule } from "./requests/requests.module";
import { CategoriesModule } from "./categories/categories.module";
import { ItemsModule } from "./items/items.module";
import { UserInjectMiddleware } from "./middleware/user-inject.middleware";
import { TrackerModule } from "./tracker/tracker.module";
import { ScheduleModule } from "@nestjs/schedule";
import { SerialsModule } from "./serials/serials.module";
import { SocketModule } from "./socket/socket.module";
import { StoragesModule } from "./storages/storages.module";
import { AuthModule } from "./auth/auth.module";
import { APP_GUARD } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AzureValidatorGuard } from "./auth/azure-validator.guard";
import { RolesGuard } from "./auth/roles.guard";
import { StatisticsModule } from "./statistics/statistics.module";
import { config } from "./dataSource.config";

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `../.env.${env}`,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(config),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    process.env.EASYPOST_APIKEY ? TrackerModule : null,
    UsersModule,
    GroupsModule,
    RequestsModule,
    CategoriesModule,
    ItemsModule,
    SerialsModule,
    StoragesModule,
    SocketModule,
    AuthModule,
    StatisticsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AzureValidatorGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: RolesGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(UserInjectMiddleware).forRoutes("*");
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us that module?

Comment: @MicaelLevi Hi, I have updated my question with the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `imports` array shouldn't have that `null` element (nor `undefined`). That's why.

Instead, if you really want to use the ternary operator like that, you could do:

```
imports: [
  process.env.EASYPOST_APIKEY ? TrackerModule : class NoopModule {},
]
```